# What is wrong with this formula of a reciprocal functional?

Tags: geometry

http://s11.postimg.org/7qrvktocj/Reciprocal.png

My answer: $-\frac{1}{x+3}-\frac{1}{x-4}-2$   is incorrect, but I'm not sure why.

What do I need to change in order to get the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

What you know from the figure are :

1. Vertical asymptotes at $x=-3, x=4$ : Assuming it is a rational function and these are the only asymptotes, we see that
   $$
   f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{(x+3)(x-4)}
   $$
2. Horizontal asymptotes at $y=0$ : Implies that $deg(g(x)) \leq 1$, so write
   $$
   f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{(x+3)(x-4)}
   $$
3. $f(0) = -2$ : Tells you that $b=24$, so
   $$
   f(x) = \frac{ax+24}{(x+3)(x-4)}
   $$
4. $f(3) = 0$ : So $a = -8$, whence
   $$
   f(x) = \frac{-8x+24}{(x+3)(x-4)}
   $$

Answer (score 0):

According to your plot, the function looks to be something like

$$y = \frac{A}{x+3} + \frac{B}{x-4}.$$

For $x=0$, $y=-2$ and for $x=3$, $y=0$. So, we have two simple linear equations for two unknowns $A$ and $B$ the solution of which being $A = -\frac{48}{7}$ and $B = -\frac{8}{7}$.